# How can I install a new theme in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, install

I want to install a new theme in Magento and I have also followed steps of this link (https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_themes.htm), but I am not able to get the theme in Magento.

Please help me on how to install a Theme on Magento.

Comment: Can you add to your answer what steps (from that link) you have taken and where you got stuck? Right now we don't know anything about what you have already tried so it will be really hard to help you

Answer (score 1):

the example you linked works if the theme comes packed as a magento extension only.
But here is an other way to to it.
Unzip the archive you have and copy the folders over your magento instance making sure that the folders with the same name overlap. (`app` over `app`, `skin` over `skin` and so on).

Then go to `system->configuration->design.`
If your theme comes in a separate package then fill in the package name in the `Package->Current Package Name`. You can figure out if the theme package name by looking in the archive inside the `app/design/frontend` folder. The folder you find inside it it's the package name. If the value is `base` then leave that field empty.
Then fill in the fields `Translations`, `Template`, `Layouts`, `Skin` with the name of your theme. The name of your theme is the folder name located inside the package folder mentioned above.

Save the configuration and clear the cache.

If it doesn't work, check in `System->Design` if you don't have a theme set there. That setting overrides the settings mentioned above. If you have records in this grid, delete them.